# In the Results Pane, Display decimal field value with right alignment:

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, alignment

I have one table called EmployeeSalary with two columns EmpID(int) and Salary(decimal(15,2))

While selecting the Table, The Results in the Results Pane is like below:

SELECT * FROM EmployeeSalary

```
   EmpID        Salary
  ------       --------
     1           5000.00
     2           12000.00
```

But I want to display the salary with right alignment like below;

```
   EmpID        Salary
  ------       --------
     1           5000.00
     2          12000.00
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @MaxLength DECIMAL(18,2) 
SELECT @MaxLength =  MAX(LEN(Salary)) FROM EmployeeSalary
SELECT LEN(Salary), REPLICATE('  ', @MaxLength - LEN(Salary))+ CAST(Salary AS VARCHAR)  FROM EmployeeSalary
```

Answer (score 1):

This should provide your answer...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178782(v=SQL.90).aspx

Query->Query Options->Results->Text->Right Align Numeric Values